# JPA mapping in 2 entities to model 2 tables having reciprocally a foreign key each other

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to create the JPA entities from an existing Oracle database that i am not allowed to change the structure.

In this existing Oracle database that i can not change, i have 2 tables :

- a table A that presents a foreign key to the table B
- a table B that presents a foreign key to the table A

There is NO assocation table between tables A and B.

I have created an entity corresponding to the table A and another entity class corresponding to the table B.
But i can not find the good relationship between these 2 entities.

@OneToMany in these 2 entities is not good.

But @ManyToMany does not convince me too.

Please, have you an idea of a correct mapping for this strange relationship between 2 tables ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify the table's structure? For example, provide CREATE statements.

Comment: Why are you looking at collection relationships for what seems like 1:1s? Each relationship (fk) is independent, so java classes (entities) should be treated as such too. Departments and Person; a Person may belong in a department, while a department may have a single person as the department head - both are mapped in the DB with the table having a foreign key, but in the object they would be ManyToOne (person->department) and OneToOne (department->person) - both are really just 1:1 relationships.